# Initialize and pass database name as parameter to DbContext object having scope of whole class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oop, session

I am developing a multi-tenant MVC 5 app using EF 6. For each user I have override the Entities Constructor to get a database name as a parameter. I have stored the database name in another code first database maintained against all users. When a user logged in, his database name is loaded in a session and then it will pass to the Entities constructor. All is good but here is the problem,

I want to declare the Entities object having scope of class in my controllers. Now:

1. A session is only accessible inside a method(ActionResult), so cannot be used in a class scope.
2. Static variables cannot be used.
3. The app can work if I initialize the entities object inside all ActionResults which uses Entites, but I don't want to initialize an object again and again.
4. There is no connection string maintained in the Web.config file, ConnectionString is generated inside the code against the database name passed as a parameter, So I cannot use ConfigurationManager class.

What I want to do is:

```
public class ABCController : BaseController //BaseController has all Sessions
{
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities("dbName"); //dbName is a session
    // all code and ActionResults here
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `DbContext` in general isn't fit to be a class level field. It's something you should instantiate when needed and dispose of when you're done. Any reason you're going down this path?

Comment: I am using MyEntities object "db" in a lot of methods, so I don't want to instantiate it again.. If I declare it at class level then I think that .NET itself disposes of the object after every call.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. .NET won't dispose the class unless you explicitly dispose it yourself. If a *finalizer* is to be ran, then it may, at arbitrary time close all unmanaged resources for you. Still, `DbContext` is ment to work exactly as I stated above. Don't worry about allocation issues, worry about the correctness of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app can work if I initialize the entities object inside all ActionResults which uses Entites, but I don't want to initialize an object again and again.

Why not?  That's exactly what you should be doing.

Even if it were a class-level member, controller instances don't persist across requests.  So you'd be instantiating it for every request a user makes anyway.  All this approach does is move that instantiation to before the user context is made available.

Any time a user makes a request to the application, you have that user's context.  (In this case from session.)  That context includes the key for your database connection.  So any time a user makes a request, use that key to create the database connection.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, So, it means that I was using wrong approach. Thanks for guiding me